# Counting functions in C source code

Tags: c, instrumentation

I have complete project in C, which can be built with gcc or Visual Studio. There are no calls to external libraries.

I would like to know how many functions there is in that project.

There are no unused functions in source code, and the project comes with tests which run it with different params, so for a dynamic approach (e.g. run-time call tree) I would need to accumulate results after each test.

Are there any tools that can perform static **or** dynamic analysis?

Comment: I'm sure that your code is calling functions from the standard C library (like `printf`...) so you do have at least one external library, the standard C one...

Comment: Well, actually you can't be sure about that. This is complex calculation engine and system calls are intentionally omitted whenever possible. Even if there are some, it's like 5 vs 2000, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: But `printf` is not a system call. My point is that a portable C application code (not a free standing one) which does not use the standard library is useless (unless it uses other libraries) because it is not able to do any input or output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `gcc`:

```
$ nm elf_file | grep "T " | grep -v " _" | wc -l
```

Note that  `gcc` can inline some functions even with optimizations disabled, so you should compile with:

`-O0 -fno-builtin -fno-inline-functions-called-once`

(`-finline-functions-called-once` is enabled by default even in `-O0`)

Comment: This is *not* GCC specific, it is specific to ELF files.... (and many Linux or other Unix systems...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well the OP mentions gcc and Visual Studio in his question and this does not apply to Visual Studio...

Answer (score 4):

The definition of functions might be not as simple as you believe. In particular, functions in the C source code do not match functions in the generated assembly code, notably because of inlined functions.

<sup>The number and size of functions depend upon the optimization level and the compiler.</sup>

And many headers (e.g. `<stdio.h>`) could contain inline functions. If they are not called, the compiler probably would optimize by not emitting their code (and same could be true with some static functions). Quite often, functions declared `static inline` do not appear in the optimized code.

Likewise, some macros might get expanded into some function definitions....

If compiling with a sufficiently recent version of GCC (e.g. 4.7 or newer) you might make a simple [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) extension for that purpose. The biggest advantage is that it works inside GCC so will really count what GCC is doing... (e.g. after some optimizations).

Notice that GCC might generate or remove some functions during optimizations ([function cloning](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00279.html), [function inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)....)

<sup>GCC MELT is obsolete since 2017</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[Frama-C](http://frama-c.com) has a `metrics` plug-in that among other things computes the number of functions in your program. Just use

```
frama-c -metrics file1.c file2.c ... filen.c
```

to get as output something like:

```
          Global metrics
      ============== 
      Sloc = 2080
      Decision point = 117
      Global variables = 51
      If = 117
      Loop = 22
      Goto = 75
      Assignment = 613
      Exit point = 242
      Function = 841
      Function call = 871
      Pointer dereferencing = 447
```

Comment: +1 (I am working in the same lab as Virgile) Very probably, *Frama-C* won't for example inline functions, or remove dead functions (e.g. those provided by system headers which does not happen to be useful in the analyzed source code). On the contrary, an optimizing compiler (like GCC, even instrumented with MELT) would do that. It really depends upon what the OP wants to measure.

Comment: Indeed, Frama-C will count all the functions that are defined or declared in the source code (after link, so that if you have `extern void f(void)` in one file and `void f() {}` in another, it will be counted once. If you want to count other things, you'll have to use a code transformation plugin (or write your own if none of the existing ones does what you want) and use `metrics` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ctags and parse the tag file. A quick way would be to do something like :

```
ctags -R -f - . | grep -w f | wc -l
```

at the root directory of your project but this might not be always correct, for instance if you have a global variable like this somewhere in your tree:

```
int f;
```

Comment: Using exuberant-ctags in ubuntu I could use `ctags -R --c-kinds=f -f - . | wc -l` to do the filtering for functions, without having the limitations of the grep approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but i hope it will help others.
If you want to keep track of your function counts in C and also maintain best coding style practices. use [betty](https://github.com/alx-tools/Betty). Here is how to go about it:

Say I have a file called file.c with the following functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1()
{
    printf("This is funct1\n");
}

int func2()
{
    printf("This is funct2\n");
}

int func3()
{
    printf("This is funct3\n");
}

int main()
{
    return (0);
}
```

So when I ran Betty on my file i.e. `betty file.c` I got some style errors because I don't follow best practices here, at the end of the error messages you will see the lists of each function as follows:

[image: my own output]

You can see that I have 4 functions each on lines 3, 8, 11, and 18 and their names at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A tool for static analysis of C source code is Edison Design Group. It is the compiler front end and you can leverage it to calculate all sort of metrics for your code.